# Check if all radio buttons selected then

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to check if all radio buttons were checked and if not use alert message. Alert message works but it sends to answers.php anyways without the selected field. How to do that form action wouldn't work if an alert is true? Thank you.

count.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function () {
        count++;
    });


    $("#qSubmit").click(function () {
        if ($(':radio:checked').length !== count) {

            alert("not all checked");
        }

    });
});
```

form.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var names = {};
    $(':radio').each(function () {
        names[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    });
    var count = 0;
    $.each(names, function () {
        count++;
    });


    $("#qSubmit").click(function () {
        if ($(':radio:checked').length !== count) {

            alert("not all checked");
        }

    });
});

<form action="bbb.php" method="post" id="quiz" style="margin-top:100px;" >
        <?php

while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">';
    echo '<div class="borderis">' . $row['question'] . '</div><br>';
    $i++;

    echo '<fieldset id="group">';

    echo '<label for="' . $row['answer1'] . '"><input type="radio" id="' . $row['answer1'] . '"name="answers' . $i . '" value="' . $row['answer1'] . '"> <bled></bled>
            <span>' . $row['answer1'] . '</span></label>' . '<br>';

    echo '<label for="' . $row['answer2'] . '"><input type="radio" id="' . $row['answer2'] . '"name="answers' . $i . '" value="' . $row['answer2'] . '"> <bled></bled>
            <span>' . $row['answer2'] . '</span></label>' . '<br>';

    echo '<label for="' . $row['answer3'] . '"><input type="radio" id="' . $row['answer3'] . '"name="answers' . $i . '" value="' . $row['answer3'] . '"> <bled></bled>
            <span>' . $row['answer3'] . '</span></label>' . '<br>';

    echo '<label for="' . $row['answer4'] . '"><input type="radio" id="' . $row['answer4'] . '"name="answers' . $i . '" value="' . $row['answer4'] . '"> <bled></bled>
            <span>' . $row['answer4'] . '</span></label>' . '<br>';

    echo '</fieldset>';
    echo '</div></div>';
}

?>
<input type="submit" value="Pateikti atsakymus" name="result" class="qSubmit" id="qSubmit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep radio button form from submitting when nothing is checked jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754026/keep-radio-button-form-from-submitting-when-nothing-is-checked-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the submit event handler, not the submit button click ideally speaking, and prevent the default behavior of the form.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quiz").on('submit', function(e) {
    var totalRadio = $(":radio").length;
    if ($('radio:checked').length !== totalRadio) {
      alert("not all checked");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="bbb.php" method="post" id="quiz" style="margin-top:100px;">
  Check 1<input type="radio" name="input1"> Check 1<input type="radio" name="input2"> Check 1<input type="radio" name="input3"> Check 1<input type="radio" name="input4"> Check 1<input type="radio" name="input5"> Check 1<input type="submit" value="Pateikti atsakymus"
    name="result" class="qSubmit" id="qSubmit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default action of the button which is to submit the form

```
$("#qSubmit").click(function(event) {
  if ($(':radio:checked').length !== count) {
    // prevent submit
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("not all checked");
  }
});
```