# useState to check if all radio boxes selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I in my React Application, I have a set of mapped questions from backend data where the user selects a response with a radio button:

```
<RadioGroup row>
                  {data.response.map((dt, rIndex) => {
                    return (
                      <div className="answerContainer">
                        <FormControlLabel
                          className="MuiTypography-body1"
                          value={dt.value}
                          onChange={() => {
                            debugger;
                            setAnswer(
                              dt.value,
                              data.questionTitle,
                              qIndex,
                              rIndex
                            );
                          }}
                          checked={selectedAnswers[qIndex] === rIndex}
                          control={
                            <Radio
                              className="PrivateRadioButtonIcon-root-9"
                              required={true}
                            />
                          }
                          label={dt.value}
                        />
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
                </RadioGroup>
```

I want to disable the "next" navigation button unless all answers are checked off. I created a state called proceed which by default is false:

`const [proceed, setProceed] = React.useState(false);`

In my `handleChange` event if the number of questions is less than the number of answers, the button is disabled.

```
  const setAnswers = async () => {
    if (questionsData.length < selectedAnswers.length) {
      setProceed(false);
      return;
    }
```

Then I added this statement in my `setAnswers` handleChange function to check if the user can proceed to the next page in the stepper:

```
    if (questionsData.length === selectedAnswers.length) {
      setProceed(true);
    }
```

Finally I pass the handleChange function into my button:

```
        <button
          className={proceed ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}
          onClick={() => {
            setAnswers();
          }}
        > Next </Button>
```

The `setProceed === false` condition works correctly. `set proceed === true` appeared to be working, but I discovered if I clicked the last answer in the questions without clicking the others, `setProceed is === true` is triggered and the button is enabled, allowing users to skip the questions.

I added the `required` flag to the MUI radio button, but the function bypasses it.

Similar to [this answer on S/O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538465/check-if-all-radio-buttons-selected-then) (which is related to PHP), How can I ensure that all answers must be selected before enabling this state change in React?

Comment: can you show how the data will look like in selectedAnswers when you have checked ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the length to compare if the all the values are filled . you can use the `every` from `Array`.

If your selected Answers contains a list of boolean ( [ true, false ] ) values then you can do

```
const isAllAnswersSelected = selectedAnswers.every(Boolean)
```

`isAllAnswersSelected` will be true if all the items in the selectedAnswers is true else it will return false.

**Refer**

[Array Every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Answer (score 0):

Material UI doesn't provide validations and you must take care of validations and error state yourself.

`required` form attribute adds the asterisks to the label and not the validations.

`<Radio className="PrivateRadioButtonIcon-root-9" required={true} error={questionHasError(qIndex)}/>` will again add style level error indicators.

You can maintain a state of answered questions instead?

```js
const [answeredQuestions, setAnsweredQuestions] = useState([]);

.
.
.
const setAnswers = async (qIndex) => {
  const updatedAnsweredIdx = [...answeredQuestions, qIndex];
  setAnsweredQuestions(updatedAnsweredIdx );
  
  // check if all the questions have been selected/answered
  if(allQuestionIndex.every(idx => updatedAnsweredIdx.includes(idx))){ 
    setProceed(true);
  } else {
    setProceed(false);
  }
}
```

You can then enhance validations by tracking if question is answered and pass error prop to highlight error state.